# @types/react/index\"' has no default export.",

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using latest React, for brevity I wish to use in my code `useState` instead to React.useState.

Now I have this code:

`import *  as React  from 'react'`

How to change the import so `useState` can be taken directly?

If I use `import React, { useState } from 'react';` I get error:

```
@types/react/index\"' has no default export.",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import * as React, { useState } from 'react'
```

Or

```
import * as React

const useState = React.useState
```